# Bridge Data from MSSQL Server & Linux

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, prestashop

We have a MSSQL Server currently that contains data I need to pass to an installation of Prestashop on a CentOS machine.

I've seen ODBC thrown around loosely, but really have no idea where to start to query the MSSQL Server with PHP.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion of ex core-developper at prestashop : forget that. Prestashop is not built to run with a mssql database, you will have to change a HUGE ammount of queries in the code, spend a lot of time to optimize it for your purpose and rework some logic.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Raphael, I've found this to be very true!